Odoo installation failed on MacBook M1
I am a developper and that is my first Odoo project. I'm using iOS and I want to install Odoo from source. I'm facing an error during installation process when running this command: 

python3 odoo-bin -d odoo-test –i base --addons-path=addons --db-filter=odoo-test

The error message is
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry, neutralize
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 11, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import _monkeypatches
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/tools/_monkeypatches.py", line 174, in <module>
    patch_c_type(AttributeError, "__init__", __init__)
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo/odoo/tools/_monkeypatches.py", line 133, in patch_c_type
    cls_dict = getattr(obj, "tp_dict")
               
ValueError: PyObject is NULL```


What can I do to solve this issue ?

